# Replace variables in a document with arguments - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace, docx, text-processing

I want to replace variables in a `.docx` with arguments python. I got the script for replacement working but I don't know how to correctly print the arguments. I run my python script like:

```
$ python var-replace.py cat fish dog
```

var-replace.py looks like:
`

```
import sys
arg1, arg2, arg3 = sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3]


from docx import Document
doc = Document('test.docx')

replacements = {
    '${replace_me_1}': "print(arg1)",
    '${replace_me_2}': "file.writelines(arg2)",
    '${replace_me_3}': "(arg3)",
    }

for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
    for key in replacements:
        paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace(key, replacements[key])

doc.save('test.docx')
```

input of `test.docx`:
`

```
${replace_me_1}
${replace_me_2}
${replace_me_3}
```

output of `test.docx` after running `var-replace.py`:
`

```
print(arg1)
file.writelines(arg2)
(arg3)
```

Expected output:
`

```
cat
fish
dog`
```

How do i correctly replace the arguments to the `.docx`?

Additional question:
How do I save the docx as `sys.argv[3].docx` `(dog.docx)`?

Comment: `print(arg1)` would return `None` not `cat`.

Comment: It should be `'${replace_me_1}': arg1,'${replace_me_2}': arg2,...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you need to pass the values in as strings instead of calling them?

```
import sys
arg1, arg2, arg3 = sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3]


from docx import Document
doc = Document('test.docx')

#current - wrong approach
replacements = {
    '${replace_me_1}': "print(arg1)",
    '${replace_me_2}': "file.writelines(arg2)",
    '${replace_me_3}': "(arg3)",
    }

#possible change
replacements = {
    '${replace_me_1}': str(arg1),
    '${replace_me_2}': arg2,
    '${replace_me_3}': arg3,
    }

for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
    for key in replacements:
        paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace(key, replacements[key])

doc.save('test.docx')
```

Comment: `file.writelines()` would return `None`

Comment: @jvx8ss good correction - thanks

Comment: It works. How do I pass the arg to the doc.save("arg3.dox")?

Comment: doc.save(str(arg3)+ ".docx") - solved it myself